Setting Default Casing for Fields in C# MongoDB Driver Queries
I'm using the following C# expression:
Collection.Find(Builders<UserWebHook>.Filter.Eq(x => x.UserId, user))

This generates the following query filter:
{ userId: "abcdef" }

However, I want it to generate:
{ UserId: "abcdef" }

How can I configure the builder to use the desired field naming casing?

Suspect that you registered the camel case convention pack (CamelCaseElementNameConvention). Either you shouldn't register it when it is not required, or you need to specify the element name with BsonElement attribute to the property.

Suspect that you are registering the camel case conventional pack that results in the property field being camel case.
var pack = new ConventionPack();
pack.Add(new CamelCaseElementNameConvention());
ConventionRegistry.Register("camel case", pack, t => true);

Either you shouldn't register it if the camel case convention is not needed,
Or customizate the member (Refer to Element Name section)
With BsonElementAttribute:
public class UserWebHook
{
    [BsonElement("UserId")]
    public string UserId { get; set; }
}

or with BsonClassMap fluent configuration:
BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<UserWebHook>(cm => 
{
    cm.AutoMap();
    cm.MapMember(c => c.UserId).SetElementName("UserId");
});


It worked after adding the class map with only AutoMap invoked, even though the only registered convention was IgnoreExtraElementsConvention. Is it strictly necessary to always register a map for each class?

Hi, apologize for the late reply. AFAIK, the camel case convention will not be set as default. It is odd that you mention the field is camel case on your end and you have to work with the class map. In case you still encounter the same issue and the only way to resolve is working with class map, ya, there is probably way you should do.
